# PHP Regex to match url contains url fragment

Tags: php, regex, url, url-rewriting

I have one url fragment: `page/login` and i need to know if another url fragment contains them.

These, will match:

```
/admin/page/login/
/admin/page/login
admin/page/login
http://www.dot.com/admin/page/login
/admin/page/login?id=10
/admin/page/login/id/10
/admin/page/login/?id=10
/admin/page/login/user?id=10
/admin/page/login/user/?id=10
page/login
page/login/
page/login/id/10
/page/login/id/10
```

And these not:

```
/admin/firstpage/login
admin/page/loginOk
/admin/page/loginOk/id/10
mypage/login/id/10
/mypage/login/id/10
mypage/login
```

I tried: `page\/login[\/\s\?]`, `\/?page\/login[\/\s\?]` without any result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a word boundary so partial matches aren't matched.

```
\bpage\/login[\/\s?]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yhNsdw/1/

Also if you change your delimiter none of the forward slashes will need to be escaped.

Comment: I have added one '?' to the end. Because in regex100 some expressions are working because ending on end of line.

I have updated your demo:

https://regex101.com/r/yhNsdw/2

And this is the final expression: `\bpage\/login[\/\s?]?`

Comment: Sorry, but if url ends on `page/login` your regex it's not working. And if i add `?` to the end, then matches urls like page/loginok.

¿How can i add that url ends on fragment as a option?

Comment: Maybe `\bpage\/login([\/\s?]|$)`? That means the URL (without the query string) can end with a forward slash, space, question mark, or nothing. https://regex101.com/r/yhNsdw/4

Comment: Great! Thanks for adding the explanations